# Sublime Text 2 R Build System (source file, send selection to interactive session)

Tags: json, bash, r

The following is the description of the R build system I am using (very happy) with Sublime Text 2 on linux (Crunchbang). With it, I am able to:

- to source the current file.R to an interactive R session;
- to send the current selection to an interactive R session (supports multi selection);
- to output plots and *.Rout files (non-interactive);

[xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/), [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml), terminator (or some other terminal that supports custom titles) and a bash script (see below) are requisites. Please, attention for the locations of each file.

The **open_and_run_r.sh** script is the object of revision (see its commented lines for details). But feel free to give your considerations about the whole picture.

---

Build File:

> .config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/r.sublime-build

```
{       // source( $file ) into interactive session
        "shell": true,
        "cmd": 
        [   "echo 'source(\"'$file'\")' | xsel -i -b; if xdotool search --name 'Running R' windowactivate --sync; then xdotool key --window 0 ctrl+shift+v; else open_and_run_r.sh; fi; xsel -c -b"
        ],

    "selector": "source.r",

    "variants":
    [
        {   // send current selection of $file to interactive session; supports ST2 multi-selection as well :)
            "name":     "r_send_selection",
            "shell":    true,
            "cmd":
            [   "xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+c; if xdotool search --name \"Running R\" windowactivate --sync; then xdotool key --window 0 ctrl+shift+v Return; fi"
            ]
        },

        {   // generate custom output.Rout file (not the output.Rout from R CMD BATCH), non-interactive
            "name":     "r_output",
            "cmd":

            [   "/usr/bin/R --quiet --slave < $file > output.Rout"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Lets give a proper formatting to the bash commands:

```
# source file, note:
   # escaped \" for JSON compatibility;
   # $file is ST2 global variable;
   # 'source()' is an R command 
echo 'source(\"'$file'\")' | xsel -i -b;
if xdotool search --name 'Running R' windowactivate --sync;
    then xdotool key --window 0 ctrl+shift+v;
else open_and_run_r.sh;
fi;
xsel -c -b


# send selection
xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+c;
if xdotool search --name \"Running R\" windowactivate --sync;
    then xdotool key --window 0 ctrl+shift+v Return;
fi
```

Finally the open_and_run_r.sh script (run as program enabled).

> ~/bin/open_and_run_r.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Initializing Terminator...'
terminator --title "Running R" --command='R' &

# in this workaround
# I could not find a better way to properly 
# catch the terminator ending,
# after it receives the 'Running R' name.

a=0

while [ $a = 0 ]; do
    if xdotool search --name 'Running R' windowactivate --sync;
        then a=1;
        xdotool key --window 0 ctrl+shift+v;
        echo 'Initialized.' 
    fi;
    sleep 2; # decreasing the value increases asynchrony behavior.
done
```

---

Keymap file, for keyboard shortcuts.

> .config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap

```
[

// R Build / [ctrl+b] see r.sublime-build/source current $file into interactive R

// R build / send current selection to interactive R
    {"keys": ["super+'"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "r_send_selection"} },

// R build / generate output.Rout and plots files from, non-interactive
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "r_output"} }

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main loop of the script,
you don't need the `$a` variable.
You can use an infinite loop, 
and break out of it when the `if` condition becomes true.
You also don't need the semicolons at the end of the lines.

The script can be simplified to:

```
while :; do
    if xdotool search --name 'Running R' windowactivate --sync; then
        xdotool key --window 0 ctrl+shift+v
        echo 'Initialized.' 
        break
    fi
    sleep 2  # decreasing the value increases asynchrony behavior.
done
```

As for this comment:

> ```
> # in this workaround
> # I could not find a better way to properly 
> # catch the terminator ending,
> # after it receives the 'Running R' name.
> ```

Unfortunately I don't know a better way either.